# Ionic 2: How to show second dropdown data based on previous dropdown selection in ionic 2 with json

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a registration page in which i have 3 combobox. One contains country names, second one contains state and third one contains district.so when i select a country corresponding state should come, and when i select state corresponding district should come. I have json contaiing districts and states which in file location assets/data/region.js How can i do this? Pls help

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController, LoadingController, Loading, IonicPage } from 'ionic-angular';
import { ObsAuthService } from '../../services/obs_auth.services';
import { MatriproPage } from '../matripro/matripro';
import { LocationService } from '../../services/loc.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-matriloc',
    templateUrl: 'matriloc.html',
    
    providers: [ObsAuthService]
    
})
export class MatrilocPage{
    myjsondata: any;
    
    constructor(private nav: NavController, private auth: ObsAuthService,
        private alertCtrl: AlertController, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
        private myService: LocationService) {
        }

    selectChange(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }  
    
    public nxt(){
        this.nav.push(MatriproPage);
        
    }
    goback() {
             this.nav.pop();
}
}
```

```html
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Location Information</ion-title>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    <h1 class="h1">Location</h1>

    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-label>Country Living in:</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-select  placeholder="Select">
                <ion-option [value]="sCountry" >India</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-label>Residing State:</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col>
            <ion-label>Residing City/District:</ion-label>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
        <ion-col >
            <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="sState" placeholder="Select">
                <ion-option [value]="state"></ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
            <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="sDistrict" placeholder="Select">
                <ion-option [value]="districts"></ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
            <ion-col>
                <button ion-button full color="secondary" block>Save</button>
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col>
                <button (click)="nxt()" ion-button full color="primary" block>Next</button>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: share the json file you are having

Comment: ok i will post the json file in the  css part of the code in the above queston

Comment: @ Sivaramakrishnan how should i share my json file?

Comment: I cant edit the post

Comment: I have uploaded to my google drive.. I am pasting the link here https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fQZi2ghEsdvkjyWugYV8VpsY1JITOu7Z/view?usp=sharing

Comment: okay I will check

Comment: @Sivaramakrishnan ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created for the states and districts. So when you click the state, the districts of the selected state will be loaded here.

Assign the states array from the json to the `states`. When you select the state the corresponding district of that state will be loaded. I have done this for the states and districts you can do the same way for country also.

**In html**

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedState">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let stateObj of states" [value]="stateObj">{{stateObj.state}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectedDistrict">
        <ion-option *ngFor="let district of selectedState.districts" [value]="district">{{district}}</ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
</ion-content>
```

**In ts**

```
states  = []; // Assign the states from the json file
selectedState: any = {
districts : []
};
selectedDistrict: string;
```

Comment: I didnt understand what to do in ts file. Can you explain it clearly?

Comment: I have created the variables in the ts file. You have to do this in the matriloc component

Comment: thats ok bro.. i got it.. so inside the states array we have to paste the name of the states? or the whole content of json file?

Comment: I did this but I got an error. Uncaught. cannot read property districts of undefined

Comment: we have to copy states to state and districts to districts?

Comment: no only states from the json has to be assigned to the states array

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189167/discussion-between-sivaramakrishnan-and-aseel-ali).

Comment: so we dont have to paste anything in districts?

Comment: hi bro.. can you help me with this please.. link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55114149/ionic-2-searhing-with-json-parsing

Answer (score 0):

You want to change the values of district dropdown based on the selected state. So what you have to do is first load the states on page load and assign them to states array. Whenever user changes the state, reload the districts array. So your code will be something like this:

in ts file

```
selectedState;
selectedDistrict;
states = [];
districts = [];

ionPageDidEnter(){
   //Load all the states and assign to states array
}

loadDistrictsForSelectedState(selectedState : StateObject){
   //write your logic to get districts from json
   districts = newArrayOfDistrictsFetchedFromJson;
}
```

html:

```
<ion-row>
        <ion-col >
            <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="selectedState" ionChange = "loadDistrictsForSelectedState(selectedState) placeholder="Select">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">
                    {{state.name}}
                </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col >
            <ion-select  [(ngModel)]="selectedDistrict" placeholder="Select">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let district of districts" [value]="district">
                   {{district.name}}
                </ion-option>
            </ion-select>
        </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

You can use the same logic for loading states based on selection of country.